# how to create an iphone Application that uses its GPS system

Tags: iphone, gps

I am fairly new to iPhone development. Right now, I am working on an iPhone game that is being developed in cocos2d. But I want to create an iphone application that uses its GPS system. I searched a lot on net but didn't find much.

I want to know about:

1. What framework tou use like cocoa touch or cocos2d,etc?
2. Any linksk that could help me regarding this?
3. Any other relevant and helpful information?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454197/how-to-get-the-current-location-of-iphone-through-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488088/iphone-gps-development-tips-tricks , among many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the Core Location framework. Everything you need to know is [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/index.html).