# Getting GPS Data data of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gps

I was just wondering what a good way would be to get the user's current location through their iPhone. I know you can get GPS data from pictures but how can I actively get the GPS data while the user is using my app. Any help pointing me in the right direction to get me started would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you really are supposed to do at least some research before asking the question, like e.g. typing "get location iPhone" into Google.

Comment: I did. The tutorials and suggestions I found all talked about how to get the data from a picture stored on the phone.

Comment: I typed "get location iPhone" into Google and this was the top hit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454197/how-to-get-the-current-location-of-iphone-through-code

Comment: Well I typed 'gps location iphone' and 'gps data iphone' and it gave me completely different links. I just searched differently which doesn't mean I didn't do research before this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework you are looking for is Core Location. Try a tutorial out on Core Location, and you should be headed in the right direction.

Here is one that looks nice:
http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/

Comment: I like this tutorial. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I get the location without using Core Location Framework?

Comment: No, that is the only official way to get location. Why can't you use Core Location?

Answer (score 1):

A tutorial such as [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application) should point you in the right direction.